# The equivalent of c# virtual in vb when calling method *within* base class

Tags: vb.net, oop, overriding

I understand how to use VB's `Overridable` and `Overrides`, to get similar functionality to c#'s `virtual` when calling methods of a class. However, consider the c# console code below, which calls an overridden method from **within** the class itself:

```
class Program {
  static void Main(string[] args) {
    new test();
    new test2();
    Console.ReadKey();
  }
}

public class test {
  public test() {
    hello();
  }
  public virtual void hello() {
    Console.WriteLine("hello from base method");
  }
}

class test2 : test {
  public override void hello() {
    Console.WriteLine("hello from overridden method");
  }
}
```

The result I get, predictably, in c# is:

> hello from base method
>   hello from overridden method

The problem is, I can't work out how to duplicate this functionality in VB.NET. Keep in mind here that `hello()` is being called from **within the base class** code, which runs the overridden method. That is what I can't seem to accomplish in VB.

No matter what I try in VB, the *base class's* hello() is always called, not the overridden hello().

Comment: Can you show the VB code you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Class Test:

```
Public Class Test

    Public Sub New()
        Hello()
    End Sub

    Public Overridable Sub Hello()
        Console.WriteLine("hello from base method")
    End Sub

End Class
```

Class Test2:

```
Public Class Test2
    Inherits Test

    Public Overrides Sub Hello()
        Console.WriteLine("hello from overridden method")
    End Sub

End Class
```

Sub Main:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim x As New Test
    Dim y As New Test2
End Sub
```